# Bypass Gradle Unit Tests in Azure Devops?

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, android-unit-testing

We have a Azure Pipeline with Gradle Task which runs almost 1700 unit tests. There are some flaky tests (2-3)which is causing the build to fail or partially succeed. Is there a way that I can bypass these flaky tests and have the build run successfully? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In `build.gradle`, add this:

```
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures).

Better still, if you know exactly what are the flaky tests, you can exclude them as follows:

```
test {
    // explicitly exclude tests
    exclude 'org/boo/**'
}
```

And if there is no choice, or you are in a rush, you can skip all the tests:

```
gradlew build -x test
```